# Property of matrix with triangular inequality?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

So, I have a square matrix $M = \{a_{ij}\}$ of dimensions $n x n$.

I know that the values on this matrix respect the so-called triangular inequality, that is:

$a_{ik} + a_{kj} \geq a_{ij},\ \forall i,j,k = 1,\dots,n$

Furthermore, I know that $a_{ij} \geq 0,\ \forall i,j = 1,\dots,n$.

Then, I would like to know if, for matrix $M$, it is possible to prove that any pair of values $a_{ij}$ and $a_{kl}$ can differ by at most $\alpha$%. Alternatively, can I deduce any relation between pairs of values in $M$ by using the fact that triplets respect the triangular inequality? I am looking specifically at relations that say something about the differences in value of any two pairs (relatively and not absolutely, since the latter depends on the values in the matrix themselves).

Comment: Cross-posted at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50374/relative-value-difference-in-arcs-of-a-directed-graph